# Custom CSS to create WordPress dropdown menu

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigation, navbar

I need to transform a regular nav bar into a dropdown menu at a page but am getting muddled with the code. Here is the existing code.

Below is the CSS for the #header and #mainnav - could someone please help and point out where I need to add the dropdown bits? I'm getting really confused and nothing seems to work Posted Image

```
**header

*******************/

#header {

background:url(images/bgHeader.jpg) no-repeat center top;
height:274px;
}

#header h1
{
float:right;
width:280px;
height:200px;
margin:0 0 21px 0;
}

#header h1 a
{
display:block;
width:280px;
height:200px;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

#header h2
{
margin:0 0 0 0;
color:red;
float:left;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

#header #mainNav
{
/*clear:both;*/
float:left;
width:750px;
height:52px;
}

#header #mainNav li
{
display:block;
float:left;
margin-right:30px;
width:auto;
}

#header #mainNav li#menu-item-56
{
    width:87px;
}

#header #mainNav li#menu-item-54
{
    width: 86px;
}

#header #mainNav li#menu-item-53
{
    width: 76px;
}

#header #mainNav a
{
font-size:14px;
line-height:14px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
font-weight:bold;
padding-top:13px;
display:block;
}

#header #mainNav li.current_page_item a,
#header #mainNav li.current_page_parent a,
#header #mainNav li a:hover
{
background:url(images/bgMenuActive.jpg) no-repeat center top;
color:#f2152a;
}


#header .social
{
width:171px;
float:right;
margin:13px 0 0 0;
}

#header .social li
{
margin:0 0 0 9px;
}
```

Could anyone possibly help?

Comment: This sounds to be just spam.

Comment: Noooo, I'm sorry it sounds like spam :(  

I just need to know how to add the correct CSS to format the li bit (and where to insert it etc).  It may be obvious but I've tried lots of things and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you what to add dropdowns to the menu? If the theme allows it - You can use the wordpress built in menu editor in the admin to add sub items to your menu.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Otherwise it's going to take more than CSS to add dropdowns.

Comment: Thank you.  I know how to add the menu items using the 'Menu' tab under 'Appearance', but I need to change the background colour and font on the dropdown section.  

I need to set the CSS styling for the li li (dropdown) but don't know what code to use?

I've tried this but it didn't work :0( :

#header #mainNav li li
{
display:block;
float:left;
margin-right:30px;
width:auto;
}